# cmsplugin_blog shows empty site when I use it as apphook

Tags: django, django-cms

I don`t get the cmsplugin_blog working in my Django CMS 2.2 app:

I made all the steps from http://cmsplugin-blog.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

Then I choosed the Blog-Application for one of my CMS-Pages. But the page is empty. Even the header from my base template is not included. The source code of the page I get is only:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS feed" href="/de/news/rss/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS feed (any language)" href="/de/news/rss/any/" />
```

The source code of my template is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}
{% load menu_tags %}

{% block base_content %}
    {% block left-col %}{% endblock %}
    {% block right-col %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Has somebody an idea what I missed?

When I try to include the blog application as plugin on another CMS Page, it works.

Are there any other docs for cmsplugin_blog than http://cmsplugin-blog.readthedocs.org/en/latest, and I am just to stupid to find them?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have a "base_content" in your base.html? What happens if you add some plain html - {% block base_content %}<h1>test</h1>{% endblock %} - to your template?

Comment: Yes, I have the  {% block base_content %} in my base.html file. 
When I add some plain html in the base content, it is not shown. The source code I get is the same as above. Even when I delete everything in the template and write only a "TEST" in it, the output I get does not change.  
When I go to the "Advanced Settings" of my CMS page and remove the application everything works like it should.
I have the feeling, that there is something wrong with my url config...but the url include of the app is done automatically, right?

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem: The templates name was not right. I had to rename it to cmsplugin_blog_base.html and put it into the cmsplugin_blog Folder in my template folder.

Comment: I had the same problem, and in the end it was an error with the name of the block.  One was "content" (with the quotes), and the other was content without the quotes.  It's not the same block :)